# How do I programatically check the depth of a WebSphere MQ queue

Tags: ibm-mq

The [IBM RedBook instructions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0801_cui/0801_cui.html) didn't help.

I need to give a script a queue manager and a queue/topic name, and have it return the number of messages queued up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm probably missing something here (*turns out I was*), as it's been about a year since I dealt with MQ at all and even then it was only peripherally, but wouldn't this command from the doc you linked give you the queue depth for a particular queue?

```
Deleted old incorrect answer
```

Per Andrew's correct answer, you need to pipe the command to runmqsc.

```
echo "display ql(queue_name) curdepth" | runmqsc queue_manager_name
```

Comment: Turns out I needed to use amqspsd to resolve the name of the queue.  After resolving I was able to use runmqsc.

Comment: Which version of MQ does this work on? I keep getting invalid syntax, then the list of options.

Comment: It doesn't work on any version of MQ. `runmqsc` is interactive. You either type it on a command line then enter the commands once inside its shell, or else pipe the commands to it.  See Andrew's correct (but oddly not accepted) solution.

Answer (score 4):

This command should work:

```
echo "display ql(queue_name) curdepth" | runmqsc queue_manager_name
```